# Php external link process

Tags: php

I'm building a site that that uses php and requires passing link id of each external link through the url and extracting the id using $_GET whenever a user clicks on any of the external links. Now, I need to rewrite the external url to momentarily point to my domain to enable me extract the link id before redirecting to the external destination, like what google does with search results before redirecting. Any help on how to do this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood what you were asking...

Have a database table of the conversions (or rather: the outside links) - the primary id can be the redirect "id".
Then have a file that you use for this outside-linking, eg "outsidelink.php".
Every link then needs to be written as outside.php?id=xxx  and in the outsidelink.php you simply use the header() function to redirect the visitor (after you've recorded the fact of the request with all the details you want to; eg IP or userID, time, etc...)

Edit: oh, you first want to rewrite the external urls.  I see. My bad.
Well, assuming the data where the external URL appears is some 'content' that comes from database, you need to scan the text before output for http://, compare the url (build a regex for this),  if it looks like it's not matching the local host's url(s), then put it away in the aforementioned database, and rewrite the url to outsidelink.php?id=xxx

hope this time I got it right for you :)